# How to add custom-made bullet points?

Tags: lists

I want to write a reference with the bullet numbering of the form: [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YCBX.png)] For example,

[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YCBX.png)] Drucke, D., 1992, Reflection Properties of Curves and Surfaces, Mathematics Magazine, v.65, p.147.

is a reference in my paper. I am currently using the following code:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item Drucke, D., 1992, Reflection Properties of Curves and Surfaces, Mathematics Magazine, v.65, p.147.
 \end{enumerate}
```

As a consequence, I am getting the following output:

1. Drucke, D., 1992, Reflection Properties of Curves and Surfaces, Mathematics Magazine, v.65, p.147.

Is it possible to achieve [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YCBX.png) instead of 1. in a list?

**Update 1**
The code snippet seems to works partially:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item [[ 1]] Drucke, D., 1992, Reflection Properties of Curves and Surfaces, Mathematics Magazine, v.65, p.147.
\end{document}
```

Output: [image]

Any improvements, will be extremely helpful...

Comment: Could you clarify your question... there seems to be a difference between what you post you want and what the image displays of what you want.

Comment: I want to put square brackets around the number. Like [1] instead of 1. I'd included it while writing the question, but somehow it disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

This, for example, using the `enumerate` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate,xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[{\color{red} 1 }] % notice the space after "1"
    \item One
    \item Two
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: List with red numbers]

and `\begin{enumerate}[{[1]}]` will produce

[image: List with brackets]

You can see the documentation with `texdoc enumerate`.

Comment: Edited just one second after being marked as a duplicate. The duplicate is a better answer...